# How can I avoid NullReferenceException when overloading the constructor?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, constructor-overloading

I made up an example in order to explain better my situation

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new Lol(null);
}

public class Lol
{
    public Lol(string a, string b)
    {
        if(a == null || b == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public Lol(Tuple<string, string> k)
        : this(k.Item1, k.Item2)
    {
    }
}
```

In this case I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` in the second constructor. Is there a way to handle it from inside the method, keeping the same structure, or should I create a private method and have both constructor called this method?

Comment: If you have C# 6 (VS 2015) you could do `this(k?.Item1, k?.Item2)`.

Comment: Or don't call `this...` and do it inside the second constructor, which may be more appropriate as you are doing a different null check there.

Comment: Don't call this.  Handle any assignment in the actual second constructor.  Then, you can do null checks inside the constructor itself.

Comment: Or you change the first ctor to `Lol(str a, str b) : this(Tuple.Create(a, b))` and second ctor checks the whole tuple and its items.

Comment: @DavidG I think yours is the best way to make a well-structured code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract the logic into a helper method and have both constructors call the helper.

```
public class Lol
{
    public Lol(string a, string b)
    {
        LolHelper(a, b);
    }

    public Lol(Tuple<string, string> k)
    {
        (k!=null)
            ?LolHelper(k.Item1, k.Item2)
            :LolHelper(null, null);
    }

    private void LolHelper(string a, string b)
    {
        if(a == null || b == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing any logic, you can do:

```
public class Lol
{
    public Lol(string a, string b)
    {
        if(a == null || b == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public Lol(Tuple<string, string> k)
    : this(k != null ? k.Item1 : null, k != null ? k.Item2 : null)
    {
    }
}
```

However in more complex cases this might not work (though you should not put any complex logic in constructor chaining anyway).

Answer (score 1):

This should work with VS2015 with C#6:

```
this(k?.Item1, k?.Item2)
```

Finally:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new Lol(null);
}

public class Lol
{
    public Lol(string a, string b)
    {
        if(a == null || b == null)
            throw new Exception();
    }

    public Lol(Tuple<string, string> k)
        : this(k?.Item1, k?.Item2)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually that's not dependent on the .Net version, but the version of the compiler, specifically C#6 which is part of VS 2015.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will edit my answer, then :)

Answer (score 1):

By not passing null in the constructor in the first place. If you want your fields or properties that corresponds to a and b to be null just put it in the constructor like this:

```
private string a;
private string b;
public Lol()
        {
            a= null;
            b= null;
        }
```

In the Main() use:

```
var a = new Lol();
```

if you want to pass values, not null, use appropriate constructor.

Comment: I must check the Tuple not to be null too, and I don't need a parameterless constructor

Comment: @Phate01. You mean to check if the Tuple is initalised beforehand. Is there a script in which you would not initialise it. if not, then you do not need to check it for null. In the other case i apologise for misunderstanding you. By the way, it is better to make checks inside a property.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, you'd need to do a check in the second constructor

```
public Lol(Tuple<string, string> k)

{
    if(k == null || k.Item1 == null || k.Item2 == null)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I call the other constructor from this?

Comment: You don't. Set the fields of the class in each, and use a common initialiser function to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

My approach for this is an extension method:

```
public static class Requirements
{
    public static T NotNull<T>(this T value, string parameterName, string message)
        where T : class =>
        value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName, message);

    public static T NotNull<T>(this T value, string parameterName)
        where T : class =>
        value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Lol
{
    public Lol(string a, string b)
    {
        if(a == null || b == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }

    public Lol(Tuple<string, string> k)
        : this(k.NotNull(nameof(k)).Item1, k.NotNull(nameof(k)).Item2)
    {
    }
}
```